# Spring Integration: Reading a csv file hosted on HTTP

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to read the CSV file that is hosted on an HTTP server. When I try to read the data as a string from the HTTP-outbound-gateway it returns me empty.

```
<int:gateway default-request-channel="AdapterCollectRequestChannel"
     service-interface="com.markono.sfp.intg.adapter.ad004.AD004CollectGateway">
    <int:method name="invokeHTTP" payload-expression="#args[4]" reply-timeout="5000">
    <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8" />
    <int:header name="HttpMethod" value="GET" />
    <int:header expression="#args[0]" name="Machine" />
    <int:header expression="#args[1]" name="Process" />
    <int:header expression="#args[2]" name="ApiName" />
    <int:header expression="#args[3]" name="HttpUri" />
    </int:method>
</int:gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway charset="UTF-8"
                   encode-uri="false" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                   http-method-expression="headers.HttpMethod" reply-channel="AdapterCollectReplyChannel"
                   reply-timeout="5000"
                   request-channel="AdapterCollectRequestChannel"
                   url="{uri}">
<int-http:uri-variable expression="headers.HttpUri" name="uri" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

When I try to read the input it returns me as empty.

```
 public List<String> transform(Message<Buffer> message) {
    message.toString();

    message.getPayload();
```

Can I just read the buffer without downloading the CSV file?

[get message payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfWfi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4aJF.png)

[screenshot of wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqwMU.png)

Comment: Try with `expected-response-type=“byte[]”`. We need to understand what `Accept-Type` is valid for the server

Comment: I tried calling the data from byte[] as attached it stills show me empty. However, when I get the payload it shows empty still. Updated the post with the screenshot.

Comment: Can answer me about `accept-header` maybe you just don’t send a proper request, so server with that file rejects it. Is there such a file on-line, so I can okay with that myself?

Comment: When I try to sniff when SI perform the request it is able to get response as screenshot.

Comment: Are you able to get content with plain `RestTemplate`? Let’s narrow the problem!

Comment: One more time: what is the recommendation from the server side for this file downloading or processing as a stream? We may guess here for a long time meanwhile the answer might be just only with some simple extra header or without some header in request. For example that `Content-Type` does not make sense for the `GET` request. Too many variables in so custom requirement... The answer really depends on the server requirements.